# Android . Add a Textarea inside the canvas at the current mouse position?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to add some textual information on the canvas. When i click mouse on a point of the canvas it should shown a text area at the current mouse position. It should be also possible to select,drag and rotate the textarea.How can achieve this functionality in android?

Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may this help you

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)e.getX();
        int y = (int)e.getY();

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
TextView textView = new TextView(context); 
textView.setText("text here");
layout.addView(textView);

layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

canvas.translate(x, y);

layout.draw(canvas);
return true; 
}
```